# SQL DELETE based on JOIN and aggregate condition

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, aggregate, aggregate-functions, sql-delete

I have two tables containing a category and a date.

Table 1:

```
cat date
A   20160102
A   20160103
A   20160104
B   20170202
B   20170203
B   20170204
```

Table 2:

```
cat date
A   20160103
A   20160104
A   20160105
B   20170203
B   20170206
B   20170207
```

I now want to delete all rows from *Table 1* where the dates are equal or later than the *earliest date* of *Table 2* per category.

The *earliest date* of category A is `20160103`. The *earliest date* of category B is `20170203`. Hence, the entries `('A','20160103')`, `('A','20160104')`, and `('B','20170204')` should be deleted from *Table 1*.

For testing, I try to create a `SELECT` statement that selects the values which I want to delete. Currently I came up with this:

```
SELECT
    t1.id
   ,t1.holiday
   ,MIN(t2.holiday)
FROM
    table1 t1
    INNER JOIN table2 t2
        ON t2.id = t1.id
GROUP BY
    t1.id
   ,t1.holiday
```

The next logical step (for me) would be to add the following `WHERE` clause

```
SELECT
    t1.id
   ,t1.holiday
   ,MIN(t2.holiday)
FROM
    table1 t1
    INNER JOIN table2 t2
        ON t2.id = t1.id
WHERE
    t1.holiday >= MIN(t2.holiday)
GROUP BY
    t1.id
   ,t1.holiday
```

However, this yields the following error:

> An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: have you tried removing the where clause and add `having t1.holiday >= MIN(t2.holiday)` to the end?

Comment: thanks. did the trick. sometimes the question is too close to see it... EDIT: but when I change it into a `DELETE` statement, it seems not to work anymore...

Comment: if you can get your required id and holiday values listed by a query, then you can put that query into a WITH statement e.g WITH CTE AS (....) - then you can do the deletes as DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM CTE C WHERE C.ID = MyTable .ID AND C.Holiday = MyTaBLE.hOLIDAY)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answers the first question (about deleting from table 1)

```
DELETE t1
FROM Table1 AS t1
     INNER JOIN (
         SELECT
            cat,
            min_date=MIN([date])
         FROM
            Table2
         GROUP BY
            cat
    ) AS t2 ON
        t2.cat=t1.cat
WHERE
    t1.[date]>=t2.min_date
```